# Is there a .NET/C# method similar to StopWatch(), but for multithreads?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, testing, stopwatch

I need to measure the response time of multithreaded requests, including the parent requests and all subsequent child requests. I know there must be ways of tracking all the requests via callbacks. The closest thing I've found so far is the StopWatch() class, but this is only for single threads. Can this be applied to multithreads?

Comment: `Can this be applied to multithreads?` Yes, of course... Every thread in your multi-threaded program is just a (single) thread. So, what would stop you (aside from the implementation effort) from using several StopWatch instances for each thread you are interested in? Or are you talking about monitoring execution of background threads that are not executing your code (but in which case i would not understand why you would want to "measure" their execution time)?

Comment: New to .NET and testing someone else's code. But from what's been explained to me, you can only use StopWatch to test the response time of the parent request? The child requests are generated as needed to perform the job of the parent request. Also there will be upwards of 10k+ requests.

Comment: What about using a profiler to measure/examine thread execution time (for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/profiling/threads-view-parallel-performance)?